# Notification icons template for Android?

Tags: android, icons, notifications

Is there any tutorial about how to design a good icon to put in the status bar as a notification in an Android App?
Ideally I'm looking for a template or an icon that I can easily modify. I'm not a designer.
I need smiley faces status bar icons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download icons from the buzzbox sdk resources page:

http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/notification-icons

there is also a photoshop file you can download and modify.

There is also one simple status bar template icon in the official template pack from Android

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#templatespack

Answer (score 3):

Here is the information straight from the Android Developer's Page: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html

This also contains a link to the [icon template pack](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#templatespack)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html)!  It's a great tool for creating a number of Android icons, including notification icons.

Answer (score 0):

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.asterisk_sign, text, System.currentTimeMillis());
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0); //this is how we will launch an Activity when the user clicks the notification
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.app_name), text, contentIntent);
mNM.notify(R.string.minutemaid_service_started, notification);  //send the notification to the system, to be displayed in the notification bar
```

this is an example of how to make a notification in the notification bar that starts an activity when selected.